# c# не работает try catch

Tags: c#, try-catch

В программе не работает блок try - catch.
Вот код:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            oleDbConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr); //инициируем соединение 
            oleDbConn.Open();
            string query = textBox1.Text;
            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
            OleDbDataAdapter da4 = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, oleDbConn);

            da4.Fill(ds1, "St");
            dataGridView8.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex) // ловит исключения (пока странно работает)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите корректный запрос");
        }
    }
```

Если убрать блок try - catch, программа вылетает с ошибкой (при внесении в текстбокс некорректного запроса), а с блоком не вылетает, а просто продолжает работу, хотя должна была выдать месседжбокс. Подобный блок не работает ещё в одном месте проекта, а в другом проекте на этой же студии с аналогичным кодом работает правильно. Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема.

Comment: Вот try...catch у вас точно работает. Console.WriteLine - это для консоли, вы же сами говорите "мессиджбокс" и у вас winforms приложение судя по button3_Click - вам надо заменить на  MessageBox.Show

Comment: A BreakPoint наверное на райтлайн поставил

Comment: @Georg96 внизу возле кнопки править - есть кнопка удалить. А "закрыть" вопрос могут "админы", но при этом могут оштрафовать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если у вас WinForms, то вместо Console.WriteLine используйте, например, MessageBox.Show("Ошибка такая-то").

Answer (score 0):

В Windows Forms нельзя так просто использовать  `Console.WriteLine()`. Если Вы хотите показать сообщение пользователю тогда используйте `MessageBox.Show("Ошибка: " + ex)`.

Если же имено в консоль, Вы можете использовать `Debug.WriteLine()`, тогда сообщения будут появляться в окне Output. Не забудьте подключить `System.Diagnostics`.